# express nodejs, modularizing app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express app with the following code:

### App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes')

const app = express();


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('server started on port 3000')
})

module.exports = app;
```

### Routes.js:

```
const app = require('./app.js')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world');
})

module.exports = {
    app
};
```

When I run `app.js` in nodeJS I get the error:
App.get is not a function

1. Why isn't my app object imported in the routes.js file?
2. How can I structure it differently so I can modularize this code?

Comment: You have a circular dependency, App.js is required by Routes.js, and Routes.js is required by App.js, that cannot work.

Comment: As @PatrickHund mentioned, this is broken.

Comment: I removed the export in the routes.js file but it is still broken, how can I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use the *app* in a file that isn't the main file itself.
Do this instead:

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world');
})

module.exports = {
    router
};
```

And then in your app.js do this:

```
var routeFile = require('Routes.js');
app.use('/', routeFile);
```